# Long-ish to wider reshape of dataframe

Tags: r, reshape2

I've got a semi-long data frame in the following format:

```
| Id | Alt | Choice | Var1 | Var2 |
|----+-----+--------+------+------|
|  1 | a   | TRUE   | 58.2 |    4 |
|  1 | b   | FALSE  | 71.6 |    5 |
|  2 | a   | FALSE  | 14.8 |    2 |
|  2 | b   | TRUE   | 82.1 |    5 |
```

...that I'd like to reshape into the following format:

```
| Id | Choice.a | Choice.b | Var1.a | Var1.b | Var2.a | Var2.b |
|----+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
| 1  | TRUE     | FALSE    | 58.2   | 71.6   | 4      | 5      |
| 2  | FALSE    | TRUE     | 14.8   | 82.1   | 2      | 5      |
```

I keep thinking to myself that I ought to be able to do something like:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ... ~ Alt)
```

But that's not quite right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not using 'plyr' but rather the base function `reshape`:

```
 dat <- read.table(text=" Id | Alt | Choice | Var1 | Var2 
  1 |a| TRUE   | 58.2 |    4 
  1 |b| FALSE  | 71.6 |    5 
  2 |a| FALSE  | 14.8 |    2
  2 |b| TRUE   | 82.1 |    5
 ", sep="|", header=TRUE)
 reshape(dat, direction="wide", idvar="Id", timevar="Alt")
#-----------------
  Id Choice.a Var1.a Var2.a Choice.b Var1.b Var2.b
1  1  TRUE      58.2      4  FALSE     71.6      5
3  2  FALSE     14.8      2  TRUE      82.1      5
```

If you need the precise order you showed, it's easiy enough to use "[". Imagine we assigned the result of reshape() to "wdat":

```
wdat[c(1,2,5,3,6,4,7)]
#===============
  Id Choice.a Choice.b Var1.a Var1.b Var2.a Var2.b
1  1  TRUE     FALSE     58.2   71.6      4      5
3  2  FALSE    TRUE      14.8   82.1      2      5
```

Comment: For once `reshape` worked the way I thought it should on the first try.

Comment: This solution is **far** simpler than vectorizing `reshape2::dcast`!

Comment: Nice, that does exactly what it says on the tin. I realize that in my haste, I actually made myself more work writing the question with a simplified dummy dataset, and then pretty-formatting the tables in org-mode. I wish I could give you a second +1 for parsing my janky table format. In actuality the data I'm reshaping is from the 'mlogit' package. I should have just said, I'm trying to reshape this data: data("ModeCanada", package="mlogit") to the following format...

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to change the `value` column used each time. You won't be able to do this in a single call to `dcast`

Here is an example using `lapply` and `Reduce` to merge the results

```
library(plyr) #for . and rename
df <- data.frame(Id = rep(1:2,each=2), Alt = c('a','b'),Choice = c(T,F,F,T), Var1= c(58.2,71.6,14.8,82.1),Var2 =c(4,5,2,5))  

by_cols <- c('Choice','Var1','Var2')
df_list <- lapply(by_cols, function(value, data, formula = Id~Alt) {
     new <- dcast(data, formula, value.var = value )
     # rename not just a a
     unique_alt <- unique(data[[as.character(formula)[3]]])
     rename(new, setNames(paste(value, unique_alt, sep='.'), unique_alt))},
       data = df)

Reduce(function(x,y){merge(x,y,by='Id',all=T)}, df_list)

##   Id Choice.a Choice.b Var1.a Var1.b Var2.a Var2.b
## 1  1     TRUE    FALSE   58.2   71.6      4      5
## 2  2    FALSE     TRUE   14.8   82.1      2      5
```

## Vectorize dcast

You can use `Vectorize` create a vectorized version of `dcast`

```
dcast.vector <- Vectorize(dcast, vectorize.args = 'value.var', SIMPLIFY = F)

df_list <- dcast.vector(df, Id ~ Alt, value.var = by_cols)
```

You still need to rename `wide` columns from just `a`, `b`

```
 old_names <- c('a','b')
 new_names <- setNames(lapply(by_cols, paste, old_names, sep = '.'), by_cols)
 df_list <- mapply(rename, df_list, replace = new_names, SIMPLIFY = F)
```

An you still need the `Reduce` step

```
 Reduce(function(x,y){merge(x,y,by='Id',all=T)}, df_list)
```

The base R reshape is a far more straightforward solution.